# Center x axis labels in center of points in android MPAndroidChart BarChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Using this for [Graph Library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

[image]

How to I get this kind of output. Tried a bit not able to achieve as exactly shown in the pic.

**Output**

[image]

The labels and points are not matching. Basically each bar line should have been under x titles.

Please let me know the changes to be done. Below is the **code**

```
List<PaymentOption> paymentOptionList = homeDetails.getPaymentOptionList();

barChart.getDescription().setEnabled(true);
barChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);

ArrayList<BarEntry> values = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> typeList = new ArrayList<>();

int i = 1;
for (PaymentOption obj : paymentOptionList) {
      values.add(new BarEntry(i, obj.getCount()));
      typeList.add(obj.getPaymentMethod());
      i++;
}

XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(typeList));
barChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(0);
xAxis.setGranularity(1);
xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);

BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(values, "");
barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.MATERIAL_COLORS);
barDataSet.setDrawValues(true);

ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
dataSets.add(barDataSet);

BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
barChart.setData(data);
barChart.setFitBars(true);
barChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
barChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

barChart.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is this line:

```
xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
```

For some reason this only works for group of bars. You will have to change it to:

```
xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(false);
```